# VMware: "Unexpected response from vmware-authd: 501 Global command GLOBAL server to non-host agent targets not supported"

Tags: vmware-player

I have VMware Server 2.0.1 and VMware mui 1.0.9 installed on a remote host. When I try to connect to the server (port 902) or to the mui (port 8333) I get the following error message:

> Unexpected response from vmware-authd:
>   501 Global command GLOBAL server to
>   non-host agent targets not supported

What's at stake here? How can I resolve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222) @and

Answer (score 1):

"
If you try to connect with the old management server you will get the following.
"Unable to connect to the remote host: 501 Global command GLOBAL server-vmdb to non-host agent targets not supported."

Open a web browser and point it to your server and with the port 8222. localhost:8222 i ran on your local machine.
"

See here : http://miekungfu.com/centos53_vmwareserver